# Timeout counter continues, even if flow is paused in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I set the **Timeout** period to specific stage. As shown in below:

```
stage('Stage 1') {
  options { timeout(time: 3, unit: 'MINUTES') }
  steps {
    echo "Stage 1"
    sleep 20
   }
 }
```

When i paused the Jenkins build during the execution of "Stage 1".
It will pause the execution but counter of timeout continues. So, after timeout exceed during the Pause state .

it will show me the below ERROR after 3 minutes and when i **Resume** the build, status of build is **ABORETED**.

```
Pausing
Cancelling nested steps due to timeout
Body did not finish within grace period; terminating with extreme prejudice
```

**Question:**

When I pause the Jenkins build, it will pause the execution as well as timeout counter till I'm not resume the build.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance